# How to add logout button to my page in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt User registration form. I wanted to add registration,log-in,log-out menu to my page and i got the link of registration and Log-in by selecting user manager in menu item type. But how to get Log-out link ? to add my menu Please help me .Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 3):

You can always try to do that with the standard Joomla! module for login/logout.
To make this module, go to: Module Manager => New => Select type Login.

Comment: That worked for me, by setting to show the module at footer, it showed as full option when the user is not logged it will show username/pass field, forgot password and register new users links all together. Not sure how to get the links only to be displayed at the main menu though. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked for me in Joomla version 2.5

```
<a href="index.php?&option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>"> Log Out </a>
```

The code below will work for Joomla 3.x

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo JSession::getFormToken(); ?>=1"> Logout </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you in your template index.php

```
<?php if(JFactory::getUser()->guest): ?>
    ...do something...
<?php else: ?>
    ...do something...
<?php endif; ?>
```